# How to create writable global variable in node.js typescript

Tags: typescript, variables, global

I have declared a `global` variable

```
import * as io from "socket.io";

declare let SocketServer: io.Server
```

and tried to write in another file but this variable is read-only.

So how to make it writable?

**Update**

```
// global.d.ts 
import * as io from "socket.io";

declare global {
  let server_socket: io.Server
  let user_socket: io.Socket
}

// server.ts
import * as io from "socket.io";

console.log(server_socket)
```

[image]

Comment: "and tried to write in another file"... can you elaborate? `declare` only tells TypeScript that the variable exists somewhere, it's not actually creating the variable for you, which is why you get the crash below. If you want to instantiate `SocketServer`, you'd still need to do `new io.SocketServer(...)`. Or assign `io.SocketServer` to your `SocketServer`

Answer (score 2):

In TypeScript, `declare` blocks are used to *describe* your global variables. In other words, they are a way of telling TypeScript what it can expect in the global namespace — but it's your responsibility as a developer to make sure they are actually there.

The way you can create (and describe) global variables depends on the platform.

**The browser (DOM)**

```
import * as io from 'socket.io';

window.SocketServer = io.default();

declare global {
  interface Window {
    SocketServer: io.Server;
  }
}
```

Requires `@types/socket.io`. Is consumed by accessing `window.SocketServer`.

**Node.js**

```
import * as io from 'socket.io';

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      SocketServer: io.Server
    }
  }
}

global.SocketServer = io.default();
```

Requires `@types/socket.io` and `@types/node`. Is consumed by accessing `global.SocketServer`.

**Universal**

You can also describe a variable that is already a part of your environment and is accessible to both the client and the server.

An example of such a variable would be `process` — it's a part of Node.js environment, but build tools like Webpack can expose its contents to the client.

```
import * as io from 'socket.io';

declare global {
  var SocketServer: io.Server;
}
```

Comment: You still need to import `import * as io from "socket.io"` in order to use it.

Comment: I thought you had already created your global variable and were looking only for a way to tell TypeScript about it. I updated my answer to cover how both can be done.

Comment: Actually I am developing a `MEAN` app. `Angular7` & `REST Api` depends on same configuration files created by `Angular`. Getting error like Property 'SocketServer' does not exist on type 'Global'.