# Typescript - How to declare global variables on node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

How to declare some custom variables globally?

#### Usage Example

```
import './logger'; // custom module: Global logger is initialized. (using winston)

log.info('This is custom global logger.'); // access to log variable globally.
```

Comment: maybe globalThis? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Comment: @ShanonJackson on node.js, not in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, declare global block's are used to describe to add a variable to global namespace or declare a global variables.

Node.js

```
import * as io from 'socket.io';

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      SocketServer: io.Server
    }
  }
}

global.SocketServer = io.default();
```

Note : Global variables are fine in some cases, even with multiple processes. Its recommended / commonly used when we have want to store a constant values, example some email ids during failures ex. global.support_email = "somedl@domain.com"

Ref might be duplicate:

[How to use global variable in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987444/how-to-use-global-variable-in-node-js)

[How to create writable global variable in node.js typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53897466/how-to-create-writable-global-variable-in-node-js-typescript)  (Using Typescript)

[How to use global variable in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987444/how-to-use-global-variable-in-node-js)

Comment: Thank you. I solved. In my case,
`import * as winston from 'winston'; declare global {  namespace NodeJS { interface Global { log: typeof winston.Logger; } } const log: winston.Logger; }`

Comment: Thats great to hear